# Validity of data

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

I have a data set that is pivoted in to the following format:

[key] [id] [0] [1] [5] [10] [15] [60] [120] [180],.. [365]

So key could be

[Products] [1000] [15,000] [4000]... etc

Where products is the category of item being reviewed and key is the identifier for the product; the only fields (0, 1,... 180,.. [365]) are individual daily samples identify how many of "x" product were logged as either sold, in-stock etc.

What I need to do is perform some kind of analysis on an entire slew of products and their inventory levels. i.e. each import of data I need to make sure the incoming data is accurate or predictably accurate and that some human did not typo a stock level. The problem is, using a simple average or rolling average can introduce significant variance and smoothing out the average renders my analysis less reliable. Ideally this analysis would trigger an alarm that someone would have to investigate.

Is there a better and more accurate way of performing this analysis?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide more information here? One way would be to see if the data forms a bell (normal) curve, and look for extreme outliers?

Comment: Could you try to explain your data format again? I don't really understand it. Also, how big is your data set.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is to identify how large an error your analysis can handle. That will make your job much easier because you won't have to find everything.

A standard way of identifying "suspicious" data is is Benford's Law, which predicts the distribution of the first digit of each number. It can also be generalized for for other digits. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford's_law

As for finding outliers, I'd probably use boxplots, particularly because you can achieve high data density with them, reducing the time to manually skim them.

One thing that might be useful is to compare the ratio of one variable to another- in my company we use this method all the time.